# Property 'createMessageComponentCollector' does not exist on type 'APIMessage | Message<boolean>'

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I am new to discord.js and such and have received an error lately.

My goal is to create a collector on a message the bot has sent.
Here is the code:

```
    const msg = await msgInt.reply({ // reply to command
        embeds: [guideIntroEmbed],
        components: [MenuRow, Cancel],
    })

    const replyMsg = await msgInt.fetchReply() // fetch the reply message

    const filter = (btnInt: Interaction) => {
        return msgInt.user.id === btnInt.user.id
    }

    const collector = replyMsg.createMessageComponentCollector({ // error is happening
        filter,
        max: 999,
        time: 120000
    })
```

I know it is possible to use ".createMessageComponentCollector()" on a message but when I try to it gives me the error

> Property 'createMessageComponentCollector' does not exist on type
> 'APIMessage | Message'.

Could someone help me out please? please do not judge me as I am new to all of this.

Comment: Although not the most secure fix, try casting `replyMessage` as a `Message`

Answer (score 0):

Tried casting replyMessage as a Message which fixed it.