# Property 'createMessageComponentCollector' does not exist on type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I ran into this strange problem, when I try to create a message component collector in a channel, it says:

```
Property 'createMessageComponentCollector' does not exist on type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
Property 'createMessageComponentCollector' does not exist on type 'StageChannel'
```

the interaction is the base `CommandInteraction` from discord.js. The strange part is I have another discord bot with using the same discord.js version (14), and there it works perfectly.

```
let cl = int.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();
```

Comment: Is this a ts error or runtime error?

Comment: ts error, it's very annoying because i have to override the type to any and i dont get any type coming from the collector

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284691/property-createmessagecomponentcollector-does-not-exist-on-type-apimessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but its worth a shot. Try checking the channel type before creating the collector.

```
import { ChannelType } from 'discord.js';
if(int.channel.type !== ChannelType.GuildText) return;
...
let cl = int.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();
```

If all else fails you can manually cast the type (generally not suggested).

```
import { GuildBasedTextChannel } from 'discord.js';
...
let cl = (int.channel as GuildBasedTextChannel).createMessageComponentCollector();
```

**EDIT**
To add on to Wesley LeMahieu's comment, and although it may be entirely unrelated, consider changing your command type from

```
CommandInteraction
```

to

```
ChatInputCommandInteraction<"cached">
```